# How is concatenating files before compressing more effective than just compressing files?

Tags: compression, concatenation, storage

In "Cracking the PM Interview", Lewis Lin recommends concatenating files before compression them in order to reduce storage size for gmail and I'm wondering why this works better than just compressing files.

Comment: When there are similar parts in two different files, classic universal multiple-files-to-single-archive compressor will pack each file individually and will have no chance to find inter-file match. With concatenation (unix-style tar + some compressor, or solid mode of some archivers like 7z or rar, check http://www.peazip.org/what-is-solid-compression.html & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression) and large enough windows (of repetition search - so don't use ancient gzip with huge files, use xz/7z) compressor may be able to catch the inter-file repeat of some data fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Compressors all use the information in the data stream so far to compress the data that follows. They generally have a window over which that history is available to the compressor, varying from 10's of KB to hundreds of MB. The more history they have, the better the modeling of the subsequent data is (assuming some level of similarity across the stream), and so the better the compression is.

Compressors are therefore particularly poor at compressing very short files. If however you concatenate similar short files, you will get much better compression on the concatenation than you will on those short files individually. As an example, source code tends to be a collection of many short files, but with lots of similarity across them. You can see significant benefit to compressing them together as opposed to separately.

The .zip format compresses all files separately, whereas the .tar.gz format compresses the archive as a whole, so effectively concatenated (with some small headers in between). It was observed early on that there was a significant difference between the compression effectiveness of the two on source file archives, even though they were both using the same compressed data format (deflate). Other compressors that are like zip and normally compress files separately will also have a "solid" compression mode that concatenates, such as RAR and 7z. This takes away the ability to easily modify or remove individual entries, but that is an uncommon use case. More often archives are simply built as a whole, and then later completely extracted.